# How do I remove values from one y-axis when having multiple axes?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, axes, multiple-axes

How do I remove the values from the right y-axis in this multiple axis plot? [Code source.](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/graph-with-multiple-x-axes-and-y-axes.html)

```
figure
x1 = Pmax;
y1 = FuelCons;
line(x1,y1,'Color','r')
ax1 = gca; % current axes

ax1_pos = ax1.Position; % position of first axes
ax2 = axes('Position',ax1_pos,...
    'XAxisLocation','top',...
    'YAxisLocation','right',...
    'Color','none');

x2 = Cdrag;
y2 = FuelCons;
line(x2,y2,'Parent',ax2,'Color','k')
```

Answer (score 1):

Setting the `YColour` attribute of the axis to `none` may be an implementation to consider. It's good to consider that `gca` is the most current axis previously called in the code.

[image: Hidden Right Y-Axis]

```
figure

x1 = 0:0.1:40;
y1 = 4.*cos(x1)./(x1+2);
line(x1,y1,'Color','r')
ax1 = gca; % current axes
ax1.XColor = 'r';
ax1.YColor = 'r';

ax1_pos = ax1.Position; % position of first axes
ax2 = axes('Position',ax1_pos,...
    'XAxisLocation','top',...
    'YAxisLocation','right',...
    'Color','none');

set(gca,'YColor','none')
```